# Sorting enormous dataset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bigdata

I have an enormous dataset (over 300 million documents). It is a system for archiving data and rollback capability.

The rollback capability is a cursor which iterates trough the whole dataset and performs few post requests to some external end points, it's a simple piece of code.

The data being iterated over needs to be send ordered by the timestamp (filed in the document). The DB was down for some time, so backup DB was used, but has received older data which has been archived manually, and later all was merged with the main DB.

Older data breaks the order. I need to sort this dataset, but the problem is the size; there is not enough RAM available to perform this operation at once. How I can achieve this sorting?

PS: The documents do not contain any indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do an efficient sort without an index. If you had an index on the date field then things would already be sorted (in a sense), so getting things in a desired order is very cheap (after the overhead of the index).

The only way to sort *all* entries without an index is to fetch the field you want to sort for every single document and sort them all in memory.

The only good options I see are to either create an index on the date field (by far the best option) or increase the RAM on the database (expensive and not scalable).

*Note: since you have a large number of documents it's possible that even your index wouldn't be super scalable -- in that case you'd need to look into sharding the database.*